# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined #3090

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am creating relations between models in loopback application, but when i execute the following command 
`slc loopback:relation` I throws the following error.

**Error**

```
(node:6444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined


events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\inquirer\lib\objects\choices.js:16:12
    at Array.map (native)
    at new module.exports (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\inquirer\lib\objects\choices.js:15:26)
    at Prompt.module.exports (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\base.js:43:24)
    at new Prompt (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\list.js:26:8)
    at PromptUI.fetchAnswer (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\prompt.js:77:16)
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:63:31)
    at InnerObserver.Rx.FlatMapObservable.InnerObserver.next (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:2140:43)
    at InnerObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:1762:31)
    at InnerObserver.tryCatcher (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:63:31)
    at AutoDetachObserverPrototype.next (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:5883:51)
    at AutoDetachObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:1762:31)
    at InnerObserver.next (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:3547:65)
    at InnerObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:1762:31)
    at InnerObserver.tryCatcher (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:63:31)
    at AutoDetachObserverPrototype.next (C:\Users\DELL5110\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\rx\dist\rx.js:5883:51)
```

**`slc -v`**

```
strongloop v6.0.3 (node v6.9.2)
├── strong-arc@1.8.9 (3dd25ac)
├── strong-build@2.1.2 (a98f310)
├── strong-deploy@3.1.4 (9b29df0)
├── strong-mesh-models@8.1.0 (62e539b)
├── strong-pm@5.2.3
├── strong-registry@1.1.6 (f8c2339)
├── strong-start@1.3.4 (28c261d)
├─┬ strong-supervisor@3.3.3
│ └── strong-agent@2.1.1 (b51fc45)
├── generator-loopback@1.25.0 (6a0e2c0)
├── node-inspector@0.7.5 (16841d6)
└── nodefly-register@0.3.3
```

node : 6.9.2
npm: 3.10.9

**I am Using Mongodb with models**

here is my project

https://github.com/rizvanhaider/node-shop

Comment: I recommend reporting it here too: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues

Comment: Yes i reported there.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved by https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3090#issuecomment-274183440
The problem was mistakenly place model-config.json file in common/models/ directory.
If someone facing the same issue with loopback, check that are you following the project structure correctly, especially not extra or unwanted thing in models directory.